# Piivot table error Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've got limited experience with VBA, however, I've followed along with a tutorial on youtube, however I end up with this error. Excel says theres an error regarding tablename, however I can't seem to spot any errors. Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

```
Sub Test()

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$V$193"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table1", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="'Data-Summary'!R3C1", _
        TableName:="PivotTable4", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion4
    Sheets("Sheet8").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable4").PivotFields("ticketId"), "Count of ticketId", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("assignee id")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code was a recorded macro.  (That's how I started :-)) I modified your code to a longer but more digestible chunks.  I hope the annotations are clear to you. When you see "Ädjust" in my comment, please check the values carefully if it applies to your case.  I do not have complete picture of your entire excel so I just made intelligent guesses of your table and sheets.

```
Sub createPivotTable()
 
    'your source's rows and columns will be assigned in this variables
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim firstColumn As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
 
    'source and destination cell range address
    Dim sourceAddress As String
    Dim destinationAddress As String
 
    'source, destination worksheets and new Pivot Table
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pivotTable As pivotTable
 
    'Assign source and destination sheets here
    With ThisWorkbook
        'Adjust "Data" to your source sheet name
        Set sourceSheet = .Worksheets("Data")
        'Add new sheet; Adjust to your destination sheet name
        .Worksheets.Add.Name = "Data Summary"
        'Assign variable object to your destination sheet
        Set destinationSheet = .Worksheets("Data Summary")
    End With
 
    'Adjust "A3" to your destination cell range
    destinationAddress = destinationSheet.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
 
    'Adjust to your bounding row and column numbers that define your source data
    firstRow = 1                        'Row 1
    lastRow = Range("$V$193").Row
    firstColumn = 1                     'Column A
    lastColumn = Range("$V$193").Column
 
    'obtain address of source data cell range
    With sourceSheet
        sourceAddress = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, firstColumn), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    End With
 
    'create Pivot Table cache and create Pivot Table report based on that cache
    Set pivotTable = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches _
        .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:="'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & sourceAddress) _
        .createPivotTable(TableDestination:="'" & destinationSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & destinationAddress, _
                            TableName:="PivotTableNew")
 
    'Pivot Table fields
    With pivotTable
        'add ticketId
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("ticketId"), "Count of Ticket ID", xlCount
        'assignee id
        With .PivotFields("assignee id")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With
 
End Sub
```

If you re-run the code above for the second time, it will display an error because Excel will detect existing "Data Summary" sheet. So to make easier on you, run following code to delete the sheet that contains autogenerated Pivot Table.

```
Sub DeleteSheets()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Summary").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

You may ask for clarification.  I will try to answer while I am still here

Comment: How would I go about adapting this to dynamically select all data in the "data" worksheet rather than a pre-defined value?

Comment: @GeetPaliwal, Please click "This answer is useful" to encourage people to help you more. It won't take much of your time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the comment, "How would I go about adapting this to dynamically select all data in the "data" worksheet rather than a pre-defined value?"

Replace the following lines of code:

```
'Adjust to your bounding row and column numbers that define your source data
firstRow = 1                        'Row 1
lastRow = Range("$V$193").Row
firstColumn = 1                     'Column A
lastColumn = Range("$V$193").Column
```

With the following:

```
'Adjust the following if your data table does not start at "A1"
firstRow = 1        'Row "1"
firstColumn = 1     'Column "A"

'This will dynamically determine the last Column and last Row
'Equivalent to Ctrl + Shift + End
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, firstColumn).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = sourceSheet.Cells(firstRow, sourceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```